# How to parse a BasicDBObject into other object

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm developing  a Java application using MongoDB and Java-driver.

I need to parse a BasicDBObject into an own object of my code, and I don't know if there is a way to develop automatically.

Is it possible to parse from BasicDBObject to JSON String? Then, I could parse from JSON String to my own Object, for example with GSON library. Something like

```
    BasicDBObject object;
    String myJSONString = object.toString();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyOwnObject myObject = gson.fromJson(myJSONString, MyOwnObject.class);
```

And I don't want to add complex to my code, also I don't to add more extern libraries. I don't want to add Gson library or other.

Any ideas?? Is it possible to do this without external libraries??
Thanks!!

Comment: You can use Morphia for the purpose: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/using-morphia-map-java-objects

Comment: Thanks, @kocko I'll take into account your comment

Comment: This is very unclear. What is your purpose? The goal that you want to achieve is exactly what? To date you don'y actually say what you really want to do. And as for "no external libraries", what gives with accepting a thanks to the for the very first "external library" suggestion that came along?

Comment: @NeilLunn I give thanks to the first person that answer that I can't do in other way. I want to do the parse without use any external libraries, because I don't know if I could do this with the java driver for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer to my question

From http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-java-dbobject-to-perform-saves/

For example, suppose one had a class called Tweet that they wanted to save:

```
public class Tweet implements DBObject {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you can say:

```
Tweet myTweet = new Tweet();
myTweet.put("user", userId);
myTweet.put("message", msg);
myTweet.put("date", new Date());

collection.insert(myTweet);
```

When a document is retrieved from the database, it is automatically converted to a DBObject. To convert it to an instance of your class, use DBCollection.setObjectClass():

```
collection.setObjectClass(Tweet.class);

Tweet myTweet = (Tweet)collection.findOne();
```

If for some reason you wanted to change the message you can simply take that tweet and save it back after updating the field.

```
Tweet myTweet = (Tweet)collection.findOne();
myTweet.put("message", newMsg);

collection.save(myTweet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have taken a look at the API: Just call `object#toString()` (http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#toString()).

Comment: Yes, I know, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, did you ran the code above and didn't you get the desired results?

Comment: Yes, I don't know if there is other way to do this.

Comment: If you don't want to use GSON/external libraries, you have to write the parsing by hand, obviously.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if I could do this with the mongodb java-driver. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `Groovy with gmongo` library for that, there you have lots of handy tools for such casting.

If the language change is not an option for you, write your own reflection-based mapper. If you POJO is simple enough, the mapper shall be pretty simple.

Comment: I can't change the language :). And yes, my POJO is simple. So I think that I can do with the method that I write in the question.